# How to map values and errors on SignalProducer

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3, reactive-cocoa-4

how do I map this

```
func save() -> SignalProducer<Void, NetworkError>
```

to

```
var saveAction: Action<AnyObject, Bool, NoError>
```

i'm a bit confused with the syntax

```
service.save()
            .observeOn(QueueScheduler.mainQueueScheduler)
            .map<Bool>( _ in true) // how to map void to bool
            .flatMapError {
                error in
                // how to map to a NoError?
            }
```

also, what should be the best practice in using actions?
should the NetworkError bubble up to the controller so it can display the error in a Popup dialog?

Answer (score 3):

You ask 3 things, so let's go one by one:

> 1. Going from a `Void` to `Bool`

Assuming you have a `foo: SignalProducer<Void, Error>`:

```
let bar: SignalProducer<Bool, Error> = foo.map { _ in true}
```

> 2. Going from a `NetworkError` to a `NoError`

This is not intuitive, but you can make use of Swift's type inference and do something like this:

```
let bar: SignalProducer<Void, NoError> =  foo.flatMapError { _ in SignalProducer.empty }
```

Your `func save() -> SignalProducer<Void, NetworkError>` could then become:

```
let save: SignalProducer<Void, NetworkError> = ...
let newSave: SignalProducer<Bool, NoError> = save.map {_ in true}.flatMapError  { _ in SignalProducer.empty }
```

> 3. should the NetworkError bubble up to the controller so it can display the error in a Popup dialog?

Eventually you have to convert the error into something readable. The Controller (assuming we are talking about the `UIViewController`), could make use of a secondary entity to translate this error, into a string or a pair of strings (title + body). If you are using MVVM, the ViewModel, would that transformation.